# Using an initializer_list on a map of vectors

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

I've been trying to initialize a map of `<ints, vector<ints> >` using the new 0X standard, but I cannot seem to get the syntax correct. I'd like to make a map with a single entry with key:value = 1:<3,4>

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

map<int, vector<int> > A = {1,{3,4}};

....
```

It dies with the following error using gcc 4.4.3:

`error: no matching function for call to std::map<int,std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> > > > >::map(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)`

**Edit**

Following the suggestion by Cogwheel and adding the extra brace it now compiles with a warning that can be gotten rid of using the -fno-deduce-init-list flag. Is there any danger in doing so?

Comment: @ YGL - fixed thank you. Still doesn't solve the original problem though.

Comment: On 4.4.1, the compiler suffers a nervous breakdown (internal error).  Maybe with 4.5 it works correctly?

Comment: Is it not still missing a pair of braces? isn't `{1,{3,4}}` a single entry in the map? I.e. shouldn't it be `{{1,{3,4}}}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment above has mentioned, `{1,{3,4}}` is a single element in the map, where the key is `1` and the value is `{3,4}`. So, what you would need is `{ {1,{3,4}} }`.

Simplifying the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to map<int,vector<int>>::map(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)
```

Not a precise error, but somewhat helpful nonetheless.